# How to post row data in array using Json in retrofit2

Tags: android, json, retrofit2, rest

I am looking for post data on the server using retrofit2 in this format.

> [
> {
> "BeneficiaryNameID": 1,
> "BeneficiaryName": "Ronak",
> "RFIDTag": "00000001",
> "Village": "valsad",
> "Faliya": "valsad",
> "createDate": "10/4/2021 2:57:31 PM",
> "RehabStatus": 1
> },
> {
> "BeneficiaryNameID": 2,
> "BeneficiaryName": "Rachna",
> "RFIDTag": "00000002",
> "Village": "gurgoun",
> "Faliya": "test",
> "createDate": "10/4/2021 2:57:31 PM",
> "RehabStatus": 2
> } ]

I have searched so many links but didn't get results. I waste my 2,3 hrs. Please help me.

Comment: So what issues you are facing? Is there any error? Please explain in details

Comment: how will i do, i don't know:-  ' @POST("api/ReturnRehabRegisterPostBulk")
    Call<ResponseDatum> returnRehabRegisterPost(@Header("Authorization") String content_type,
                                                @Body String cartList' i used this, it's giving right format but not able to post by api, getting 500 error

Comment: Send this data as a String

Comment: @ChiragSavsani sending in string working on postman but not in code, because i only want json format

Comment: You have to parse your string to JSON in the backend server.